# Symfony fixtures return "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fixtures

I have such a Doctrine fixture:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Tenant;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\AssignedGenerator;
use Doctrine\ORM\Id\IdentityGenerator;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;

final class TenantFixtures extends Fixture
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $tenant = new Tenant();
        $tenant->setDomain('1.example.com');
        $tenant->setName('Tenant 1');
        $manager->persist($tenant);

        $manager->flush();

        $metadata = $manager->getClassMetadata(Tenant::class);
        $metadata->setIdGenerator(new AssignedGenerator());
        $metadata->setIdGeneratorType(ClassMetadataInfo::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);

        $tenant = new Tenant();
        $tenant->setId(100);
        $tenant->setDomain('2.example.com');
        $tenant->setName('Tenant 2');
        $manager->persist($tenant);

        $manager->flush();

        $metadata->setIdGenerator(new IdentityGenerator());
        $metadata->setIdGeneratorType(ClassMetadataInfo::GENERATOR_TYPE_AUTO);
    }
}
```

When I try to load it via `bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test`, I receive such an error:

```bash
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO tenant (name, domain) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [100, "Tenant 2", "2.example.com"]:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

How to save both entities correctly?

Note that the first one has an auto generated id, and the second one has an assigned id. This example is simplified.

Comment: Apparently it is the id that is the problem as it does not allow modification by hand (it is auto-incrementing). Can I see your entity? @tr_

Comment: I think the generator has to be changed *after* persisting (manager->persist()). Could you please try that as well and get back?

Comment: This is because you already use the manager to persist that type of class. I don't know why changing the generator after that has no effect. If you remove the persist of the first `Tenant` it will work. Maybe you can split the fixtures or looking deeper into doctrine files to find what's blocking.

Comment: Take a look at this github issue. https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/3118

Comment: @jona303, thank you. Looks like it’s really a “nuance” of Doctrine :-(

Comment: Here is a description of the issue: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/8152#issue-621500711

Comment: So bad de PR was abandoned

Comment: @jona303, the helper from the issue you mentioned works perfectly: https://gist.github.com/uginroot/33a2851d87bae3e261585c4befea35dc